# Video recording using Media session causes lag in streaming

Tags: c++, video-streaming, video-capture, audio-recording, ms-media-foundation

I'm developing a desktop application to record video and stream from USB camera using **MediaSession**. I have implemented to capture the video and audio. Also, implemented **Play/Pause/Stop** presentation state in my app but I'm facing issue after resuming the video from pause state.

Using **IMFMediaSession::Start** method, I have resumed the video capture from pause state. After invoking this method, there is too much of lag in the preview. The media samples are queued after resuming the video recording.

I have created **asynchronous media session**. Please find the following code snippet,

```
HRESULT SetTopologyFunc()
{
    hr = MFCreateMediaSession(NULL, &m_pMediaSession);  if(FAILED(hr))  {   return hr;  }

    if(m_pMediaSession != NULL)
    {
        hr = m_pMediaSession->BeginGetEvent((IMFAsyncCallback*)this, NULL); if(FAILED(hr))  {   return hr;  }
    }

    // Create a blank topology
    hr = MFCreateTopology(&pTopology);  if(FAILED(hr))  {   return hr;  }

    // Set the topology on the media session.       
    hr = m_pMediaSession->SetTopology(MFSESSION_SETTOPOLOGY_IMMEDIATE, pTopology);  if(FAILED(hr))  {   return hr;  }
}

HRESULT StartPlayback()
{
    HRESULT hr = S_OK;
    PROPVARIANT varStart;
    PropVariantInit(&varStart);
    varStart.vt = VT_EMPTY;     

    hr = m_pMediaSession->Start(&GUID_NULL, &varStart);     if (SUCCEEDED(hr))  {    m_state = Started; }

    PropVariantClear(&varStart);

    return hr;
}

HRESULT  CResumeVideoCapture()
{
    HRESULT hr = S_OK;

    if (m_state != Paused && m_state != Stopped)        {   return MF_E_INVALIDREQUEST; }
    if (m_pMediaSession == NULL || m_pMediaSource == NULL)  {   return E_UNEXPECTED;    }

    hr = StartPlayback();

    return hr;
}

HRESULT CStopVideoCapture()
{
    if (m_state != Started && m_state != Paused)        {   return MF_E_INVALIDREQUEST; }
    if (m_pMediaSession == NULL || m_pMediaSource == NULL)  {   return E_UNEXPECTED;    }

    HRESULT hr = m_pMediaSession->Stop();   if (SUCCEEDED(hr))  {    m_state = Stopped; }

    return hr;
}

HRESULT CPauseVideoCapture()
{
    if (m_state != Started) {   return MF_E_INVALIDREQUEST; }
    if (m_pMediaSession == NULL || m_pMediaSource == NULL)  {   return E_UNEXPECTED;    }

    HRESULT hr = m_pMediaSession->Pause();  if (SUCCEEDED(hr))  {    m_state = Paused;  }

    return hr;
}
```

Already I tried IMFSourceReader technique to capture video and audio together but I could not combine both. For this reason, I moved on to media session technique. Everything is working fine but I cannot control the presentation state.

To flush the queuing samples in toplogy, I have tried **IMFMediaSession:: ClearTopologies** and **IMFMediaSession:: SetTopology** with MFSESSION_SETTOPOLOGY_CLEAR_CURRENT methods before resume the recording.

Can you guide me to control the presentation state while recording the video in media session?